# GDK example code

Tags: c, gnome, gdk

Does anyone have a Gnome GDK example code or tutorials?

I know that this is getting annoying, considering so many people ask this but I've tried and tried finding a Gnome GDK tutorial, for like an hour or so and I still don't have any luck, I'm using only C programming language, thank you.

Comment: Not everything has a tutorial. Sometimes you will need to find some sample code and dig through a reference instead. Seems that way for GDK. Unfortunately. I wonder why you are choosing GDK though? Maybe there would be a better, and more well documented library for your project?

Comment: @TomDignan: GDK _is_ well documented IMHO.

Comment: @legends2k You are right, the reference manual is good. I didn't mean to say it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have stumbled over the GDK Reference Manual already but did not scroll down far enough to realize that there are actually many examples in there:

> https://developer.gnome.org/gdk/2.22/

E.g. click on `windows` then scroll down to example 7.

**113** line tutorial right there, hope this helps.

Comment: It only showed about gtk+ and not gdk.

Comment: The window-component was just an example. Keep looking there are many examples.